# Beginner - Subroutine confusion

Tags: perl, subroutine

I'm a beginner and confused about what's happening inside this Perl subroutine.

I'm using only global variables to simplify things, but it's still not working.

I'm simply trying to print a file's read, write and executable attributes using the file test operators with IF statements.

Can anyone point out the problem for me?

Louie

```
sub getfileattributes {
    if (-r $file) {
        $attributes[0] = "readable";
    } else { $attributes[0] = "not readable"; }
    if (-w _) {
        $attributes[1] = "writable";
    } else { $attributes[1] = "not writable"; }
    if (-x _) {
        $attributes[2] = "executable";
    } else { $attributes[2] = "not executable"; }
}    

my @attributes;
my $file;

foreach $file (@ARGV) {
    &getfileattributes;
    printf "The file $file is %s, %s and %s\n", @attributes;
}
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! It will immediately tell you what your error is.

Comment: Using global variables is *not* how you simplify things

Comment: Global variables don't "simplify things." They do just the opposite. When you declare variables in the smallest scope possible, it is easier to know where they came from, how they got there, and where they're going next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using global variables is usually quite bad and points to a design error. In this case, the error seems to be that you don't know how to pass arguments to a sub.

Here is the pattern in Perl:

```
sub I_take_arguments {
   # all my arguments are in @_ array
   my ($firstarg, $secondarg, @rest) = @_;
   say "1st argument: $firstarg";
   say "2nd argument: " .($firstarg+1). " (incremented)";
   say "The rest  is: [@rest]";
}
```

Subs are invoked like

```
I_take_arguments(1, 2, "three", 4);
```

(Do *not* invoke them as `&nameOfTheSub`, this makes use of very special behaviour you don't usually want.)

This would print

```
1st argument: 1
2nd argument: 3
The rest  is: [three 4]
```

Subroutines can *return* values, either with the `return` statement or as the value of the last statement that is executed. These subs are equivalent:

```
sub foo {return "return value"}
sub bar {"return value"}
```

I would write your `getfileattributes` as

```
sub getFileAttributes {
   my ($name) = @_;
   return
      -r $name ? "readable"   : "not readable",
      -w $name ? "writable"   : "not writable",
      -x $name ? "executable" : "not executable";
}
```

What is happening here? I take an argument `$name` and then return a *list* of values. The `return` keyword could be omitted. The `return` takes a list of values and does not require parens, so I leave them out. The `TEST ? TRUE-STATEMENT : FALSE-STATEMENT` operator is known from other languages.

Then, in your loop, the sub would be invoked like

```
for my $filename (@ARGV) {
   my ($r, $w, $x) = getFileAttributes($filename);
   say "The file $filename is $r, $w and $x";
}
```

or

```
foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
   my @attributes = getFileAttributes($file);
   printf "The file $file is %s, %s and %s\n", @attributes;
}
```

---

Notes:

- `say` is like `print`, but adds a newline at the end. To use it, you have to have a Perl > 5.10 and you should `use 5.010` or whatever version or `use feature qw(say)`.
- always `use strict; use warnings;` unless you know better for sure.
- Often, you can write programs without assigning to a variable twice (Single assignment form). This can make reasoning about control flow much easier. This is why global variables (but not global constants) are bad.

Answer (score -1):

You are not actually using global varaibles.  My scopes the variables them local to the main routine, so when you call the subroutine, $file and @attributes are scoped to the subroutine, not to the main routine.

Change my to our for $file and @attributes to make the variables global and available to the subroutine.

You can check this for yourself by using the -d argument for perl to run it in the debugger and check the values of the items.

Comment: Bang on!  that did the trick.  Much appreciated.  Guess I need to read further along in the book.

Comment: Bad advice; you hurt more than you helped. Using `our` = aweful. Moving `my` = poor. Using args = perfect.

Comment: Agreed.  I will rework this to make it work with args, but I just wanted to understand why the code didn't work.  Lots to learn still.  thanks for the clarification.